# Rails scopes with hash syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here are my two models:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  scope :articles_by_author, ->(author_id) {joins(:author).where(author: {id: author_id})}
end
```

I am trying to get the `Article.articles_by_author(id)` scope to work.  Basically: It should return all the articles for a particular Author.

Here is what happens:

First I grab an author:

```
author = Author.first
```

Then I run the query:

```
Article.articles_by_author(author)
```

The generated SQL seems right:

```
SELECT "articles".* 
FROM "articles" 
INNER JOIN "authors" 
ON "authors"."id" = "articles"."author_id" 
WHERE "author"."id" = 1
```

But it errors out with the following:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: author.id: SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "authors"."id" = "articles"."author_id" WHERE "author"."id" = 1

What am I messing up within this scope?  I want to keep the hash syntax within this scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `joins`/`includes` you can use model names, but in `where` clause you should use database table name, thus plural `authors`:

```
scope :articles_by_author, lambda { |author_id|
  joins(:author).where(authors: { id: author_id })
}
```

P.S. I've styled your code a bit to meet (Rubocop's) conventions :)

P.P.S. Isn't it easier (having that we know `author_id`) to just go with:

```
Author.find(author_id).articles # ? :)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  You are right: `Author.find(author_id).articles` is probably better.  This was just an exercise with scopes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you have a straight has_many/belongs_to you can do

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
  scope :articles_by_author, ->(author_id) { where(author_id: author_id) }
end
```

Or `Article.where(author_id: author_id)`

You don't need the joins